# Lisp- modifying a local variable inside multiple statements on a function

Tags: function, variables, if-statement, lisp, local

I'm new to lisp, trying to understand how lisp works, and I don't know how exactly to work with a local variable inside a large function.
here I have a little exc that I send a number to a function and if it is divisible by 3, 5 and 7 I must return a list of (by3by5by7), if only by 7, return (by7) and so on....
here is my code:

```
(defun checknum(n)
    let* (resultt '() ) ( 
      if(not(and(plusp n ) (integerp n))) (cons nil resultt) (progn 
                       (if (zerop (mod n 7)) (cons 'by7 resultt) (cons nil resultt))
                       (if (zerop (mod n 5)) (cons 'by5 resultt) (cons nil resultt)) 
                       (if (zerop (mod n 3))  (cons 'by3 resultt) (cons nil resultt) )) ))
```

but if i send 21 for ex, I only get nil, instead of (by3by7) I guess the local variable is not affected by my if statements and I don't know how to do it...

Comment: Please edit the question and improve the formatting of the code.

Comment: The result of a `progn` block is the value of the last expression in the block, and `cons` does not mutate anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(cons x y)` creates a new cons cell and disposes of the result. To change the value of a variable you need to use `setq`, `setf`, `push` or the like, for example:

```
(defun checknum (n)
  (let ((resultt nil))
    (when (and (plusp n) (integerp n))
      (when (zerop (mod n 7)) (push 'by7 resultt))
      (when (zerop (mod n 5)) (push 'by5 resultt))
      (when (zerop (mod n 3)) (push 'by3 resultt)))
    resultt))
```

or perhaps, more elegantly using an internal function to factor out the repetition:

```
(defun checknum (n)
  (when (and (plusp n) (integerp n))
    (labels ((sub (d nsym res)
               (if (zerop (mod n d))
               (cons nsym res)
               res)))
      (sub 7 'by7
       (sub 5 'by5
        (sub 3 'by3 nil)))))
```

Testing:

```
CL-USER> (checknum 12)
(BY3)
CL-USER> (checknum 15)
(BY3 BY5)
CL-USER> (checknum 105)
(BY3 BY5 BY7)
CL-USER> (checknum 21)
(BY3 BY7)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Most lisp forms/functions don't modify their arguments. The ones that do will be explicitly documented as doing so. See adjoin and pushnew, for instance, or remove and delete.

To the point of 'trying to understand how lisp works', writing the same function in various different ways helped me a lot, so you might want to think about how you can write your function without modifying a variable at all, and why and when you would want to / not want to use destructive modifications.

Something like the below makes two passes, and will be too slow if there are a large quantity of numbers you need to check, but doesn't destructively modify anything.

```
(defun checknum (n)
  (remove nil 
    (mapcar #'(lambda (m sym)
                (when (zerop (mod n m)) sym))
        '(7 5 3) 
        '(by7 by5 by3))))
```

The above approach can be written to not require two passes, etc.